# How to convert refresh function JavaScript to Ajax or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using JavaScript function to refresh page, but now I want to update it to Ajax or jQuery. I have tried below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function refresh_onclick()
{
  // ExamEndYN = "Y"; // CloseUsingX 
  EvtLog("2")
  var timeLeft = document.frmData.timeLeft.value;      
  top.fraTest.location.replace("exam.jsp?id_exam=" + id_exam + "&userid=" + userid + "&gindex=" + gindex + "&timeLeft=" + timeLeft);
}

<div class="right_bt_box">
    <a href="JavaScript:refresh_onclick();" class="button-refresh" id="Re_No" style="display:none ">Refresh <span class="icon_box icon_w icon_18"></span></a>
</div>
```

How to convert this function to Ajax or jQuery to load page without refresh page ?

Comment: if you want to load the *whole* page then just refreshing it makes sense. If you want to refresh just certain parts of the page then Ajax makes sense, and jQuery can help you do that with fewer lines of code.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ? A reload ? A navigation toward a new page ? Or some kind of transparent refresh for the user, as you could find on a single page application ?

Comment: Hi, current I wish to convert it to ajax or jquery and reload whole page, and convert base on exist parameter

Comment: @nnnnnn: can it reload and without refresh page ?

Comment: Already explained above - if you want to load the *whole* page then just refreshing is correct.  Is there a reason *why* you want to use AJAX to do this?

Comment: @Archer: I don't only use ajax, just I want to ask I can use ajax or jquery...

Comment: If you want to reload page then don't use Ajax

Comment: So, how to convert it to jquery ?

Comment: There is no point converting working Javascript to equivalent jQuery.  jQuery **is** Javacript - it's simple a Javascript library.  If what you have is working then there's no need to do anything.  If, however, you need to do something else then you need to explain *that* to us.

Comment: "convert it to ajax or jquery". These are not alternatives to choose from. They don't do the same thing. It's usually a good idea to find out what the technology you're proposing actually is, and what it can do, before saying you want to use it! And jQuery is just a library around JavaScript which makes some enhancements and has a different syntax. AFAIK there's no jQuery function to reload a page, you can just use the native one like you do already. jQuery won't make that better. And using ajax makes no sense for this because the whole point of ajax is to remove the need for page refreshes.

Comment: If you actually want to change the functionality of your page in some way, then please describe that instead - then maybe we can tell you a way to do it, instead of asking about tools that you don't seem to really understand and giving arbitrary requirements to "convert" code that already works and is not deprecated.

Comment: @ADyson: Thank for your explain..just I want to know if this case can I change it to jquery? isnt's it better? and you have replied for this: ' jQuery won't make that better'.. ^^

Comment: for the specific case of refreshing the page...no. Like I said, jQuery doesn't offer a separate function for refreshing the page. There's just location.reload() / location.replace() like you already have, which are not jQuery functions. If you're talking about changing some of the other code, then yeah you could write the "click" event handler using jQuery syntax, sure. You can find that syntax out from any basic tutorial online.